# *** Error in `./text_buffer': corrupted double-linked list: 0x089cbd98 **

Tags: sql, c, linux, malloc, freetds

I'm trying to make the app using FreeTDS. Following are my code

```
/* 
 * Purpose: Test to see if row buffering and blobs works correctly.
 * Functions: dbbind dbnextrow dbopen dbresults dbsqlexec dbgetrow
 */

#include "common.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "readline/readline.h"
#include "readline/history.h"
#include "string.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  char failed;
  int hasil;
  char ch;

  char* r = malloc(30);


  LOGINREC *login;
  DBPROCESS *dbproc;
  int i;
  int p = 0;
  char teststr[1024];
  DBINT testint;
    read_login_info(argc, argv);
    fprintf(stdout, "Starting %s\n", argv[0]);


/* Fortify_EnterScope(); */

      while(1)
      {
    char qrcode[50];
    char perintahsql[100] = "select * from REF_COBA where id=";
    char *alokasi="";

    while(ch != '\n')    // terminates if user hit enter
    {
      ch = getchar();
      qrcode[p] = ch;
      p++;
}
qrcode[p]='\0';
strcpy(r,qrcode);

alokasi = strsep(&r, ",");
strcpy(r,"");
p=0;
ch = "";
dbinit();
dberrhandle(syb_err_handler);
dbmsghandle(syb_msg_handler);
fprintf(stdout, "About to logon\n");
login = dblogin();
DBSETLPWD(login, PASSWORD);
DBSETLUSER(login, USER);
DBSETLAPP(login, "text_buffer");
//DBSETLHOST(login, "ntbox.dntis.ro");
DBSETLHOST(login, "192.168.1.9");

fprintf(stdout, "About to open\n");
dbproc = dbopen(login, SERVER);
if (strlen(DATABASE))
  dbuse(dbproc, DATABASE);
dbloginfree(login);

#ifdef MICROSOFT_DBLIB
  dbsetopt(dbproc, DBBUFFER, "100");
#else
  dbsetopt(dbproc, DBBUFFER, "100", 0);
#endif

dbcmd(dbproc, strcat(perintahsql,alokasi));
dbsqlexec(dbproc);

if (dbresults(dbproc) != SUCCEED)
{
  failed = 1;
  fprintf(stdout, "Was expecting a result set.");
  exit(1);
}
fprintf(stdout, "select\n");
for (i = 1; i <= dbnumcols(dbproc); i++)
  printf("col %d is %s\n", i, dbcolname(dbproc, i));
fprintf(stdout, "setelah for\n");
dbbind(dbproc, 1, INTBIND, 0, (BYTE *) & testint);
dbbind(dbproc, 2, CHARBIND, 0, (BYTE *) teststr);

for (i = 1; i < 2; i++)
{
  char expected[1024];
  sprintf(expected, "row %03d", i);
  if (i % 100 == 0) 
  {
dbclrbuf(dbproc, 100);
  }
  if (REG_ROW != dbnextrow(dbproc))
  {
failed = 1;
fprintf(stderr, "Failed.  Expected a row\n");
//exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
fprintf(stdout, "jalanin usb\n");
printf("Read a row of data -> %d %s\n", (int) testint, teststr);
hasil = system("/opt/usb1rc_linux USB1REL-172 R");
sleep(2);
hasil = system("/opt/usb1rc_linux USB1REL-172 r");
  }

}
dbfreebuf(dbproc);
dbexit();

  }
  return 0;
 }
```

I modified the source from FreeTDS, after compilation there are some warning

`bash-4.2# make text_buffer 
CC       text_buffer.o
text_buffer.c: In function 'main':
text_buffer.c:54:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     ch = "";
        ^
text_buffer.c:18:7: warning: variable 'hasil' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int hasil;
       ^
text_buffer.c:17:8: warning: variable 'failed' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char failed;
        ^
  CC       common.o
  CCLD     text_buffer`

I execute the program without error. This program will check input from user then run the sql command. The format of input shall be , e.g 123456,john doe then press enter. After 50-60 times of input, the double-linked list error will happen.
could anybody help why the error happen?

Comment: char *alokasi=""; should be    char *alokasi=NULL; and ch = ""; should be ch = ' ';

Comment: dear, error still happen when i input 50-60 times.